# Airtable/Excel multiple if statement help (syntax seems the same)

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, airtable

Just started up on Airtable and liking it already.

I'm looking to write some code so that if a cell in one column (e.g. October-19) is within September-November (which it is) the cell with the formula in will show 'Q1 Y2' (our quarters run September-August, don't ask why!).

The problem is I will have to do a huge nested if statement for every month, and then when we get to September-20 the formula will output 'Q1 Y3' and I'll have to run through the next 12 months. Any ideas?

```
IF({Completion Month}='October-19',"Q1-Y2",
IF({Completion Month}='November-20',"Q1-Y2",
IF({Completion Month}='December-20',"Q2-Y2", etc...
```

I've tagged this as excel as the if statement syntax seems to be the same.

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: Use a look up table with dates and quarter names.

Comment: @SJR How would I achieve this?

Comment: The simplest way would be to put the months in one column and quarter in the second, and then do a lookup.